# Getting around cyclical foreign key errors when trying to generate insert data scripts in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, scripting

I am trying to generate some insert scripts using the SQL Server 2008 Script Wizard. Upon generating the scripts, I get the following error:

*"The selected database contains foreign keys that create a cycle. Publishing data only is not supported for databases with cyclical foreign key relationships."*

I've attempted to disable and remove all constraints in the database. The error is still occurring. Is there any way to get around this? Possibly make SQL ignore the constraints while generating the scripts.

Comment: Since you should not have a design that has cyclical foreign key constraints, I suggest you first fix your bad design. Even if you can disable the constraints for the insert, it is a very bad idea as you will get data ingetrity problems. Your design is incorrect, fix it.

Comment: In addition to what HLGEM has stated, if you cannot insert data using a script directly into the database, how in the heck will the GUI be able to do it?

Answer (score 18):

On the Wizard page where you choose the radio button to select All Database Objects or Specific Objects, make sure to select All Database Objects. For some reason the tool needs something in there to generate even if you just want the table insert script.

Once I changed that radio button to All Database Objects, and selected the Advanced option to generate Type of script = Data Only, it worked all the way through.

Comment: Doing a demo data dump to a local server before a conference and the interface had changed and suddenly it wasn't working (I guess I updated SSMS or something)... this worked and saved my butt, Thanks!

Comment: And what if I want to execute the insert statements in an other database, should I execute SQL for other objects too ??

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem as the OP. Then I tried again, this time in the advanced options, for the "types of data to script" option, I selected "schema and data" rather than data only. Then it worked for me without complaining about cyclical keys.

Comment: That's a good solution for 1 table, works for me with "schema and data" rather than data only. Then it's just a case of editing the output script to leave the INSERTs (and any SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON/OFF before and after). Much easier than scripting the entire db! Thanks

Comment: This worked for my for multiple tables, even when scripting foreign keys was disabled etc. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue, and I discovered today that you can use SQL Server Management Studio 2012 against a 2008 R2 DB and you won't get the error:

[Sql Server Scripting Data Only: Workaround for CyclicalForeignKeyException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013779/sql-server-scripting-data-only-workaround-for-cyclicalforeignkeyexception)

Answer (score 2):

Saving to file vs. to a new Query editor window seems to make it work for me on Management Studio 2008 :\

Comment: Definitely a bug in SSMS. Beyond your solution, if you hit Back button and give a new try to generate on a new query window (just changing the radio button), it does generate!

Answer (score 0):

First off IMHO HLGEM's response is a bit cavalier--there are valid reasons at times to have cyclic references.

That said I think the script generator is hyper-sensitive.  It seems to think just about any PK/FK pair is "cyclic" and I ended up having to use a copy of my database from which I'd stripped all keys to get the export to get beyond the "cyclical" error.  A script like the following can help you drop keys globally but of course be careful!

SELECT
'ALTER TABLE ' + object_name(parent_obj) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + [name] 
AS Script
from sysobjects where xtype IN ('F')

[I didn't write this.  See http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=46682]

Further the tool is pretty useless in terms of feedback since its report doesn't provide enough detail to narrow down where the supposed cyclical references exist.

Finally I found the tool to be pretty flaky in that I get random timeouts.  One other observation that I haven't researched extensively is I think the tool may require you to start from scratch after the cyclical error to clear it's cache since I see different behavior when I use Previous button vs. starting afresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the data by setting the script option - "Script Check Constraints" to False

Sorry this will not work :(

You will have to determine which table is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error because I didn't had a table selected in the object list (one big table I wanted to create in another script). Selecting all of the tables solved the problem.

PD: Maybe a little bit late, but searching CyclicalForeignKeyException gets first in Google.