# Sql Server Scripting Data Only: Workaround for CyclicalForeignKeyException?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server DB that I want to script data for from a single table. When I try this I get the CyclicalForeignKeyException- presumably because somewhere there is an FK cycle, which is fine. This seems to be an annoying limitation of SQL Server, and in my case, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

The 3 suggestions I've read for this are:

1. Get rid of the cycles. (Not an option as I don't want to modify this DB.)
2. Temporarily remove the keys and reset them afterwards. (Not an option for the same reason.)
3. Script all objects in the DB. (This would be possible, but this DB is large so this it not an ideal solution.)

Another similar suggestion I read was to backup the DB and restore a temp copy, remove the FKs, then get the data. But again since the DB is large, this isn't ideal either.

Any one have another idea?

Comment: You can also change the action to `NO ACTION`.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk - Would this be making a change to the DB (not acceptable in my case), or just for running the script (acceptable)?

Comment: That would be making a change to the database. Can you use a temp table?

Comment: I could use a temp table. How do I create INSERT statements for a temp table? Note that it seems the scripting tool has the cyclical exception regardless if the table I want to script data for has any cycles or not. I think it's detecting one DB wide and it just gives up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow- I can't believe this worked...

I have a similar version of the DB I was trying to get data for on another machine. This time when I ran the tool it worked. (By tool I mean: Tasks->Generate Scripts... select 1 table, in advanced, change "Types of data to script" to "Data only".)

At first I thought this other version of the DB must not have the cyclical keys, but then I realized that I was using SQL Server Management Studio 2012 Express. So then I closed SSMS, did a runas /netonly with the domain user and opened SSMS 2012 and connected to the SQL Server 2008 R2 DB. I retried to generate the script and it worked!

Apparently SSMS 2012 fixed this "issue" and you can even use it against other DB versions!